# Clean way to continue looping until array has been filled with accepted values?

Tags: python, loops

I couldn't figure out how to tag this question well.

I need to produce a number of random 3D points with component values in a range around the origin, but such that no point is within a certain radius around the origin.

Visually this should amount to an empty sphere around the origin. I have done this by the following:

```
for Food in xrange(100):
    food_array[Food] = 20*np.random.uniform(-1,1,3)
    if mag(food_array[Food]) < 4:
        del food_array[Food]
```

mag() calculates the distance from origin, and if it is less than 4, that element is deleted. This works fine, but my question is, what is a clean way of then making the loop continue until the food_array has 100 foods?

I need this to always end with the same number of points, but obviously if I am deleting some of them, I need it to keep going until the array has 100 points. I can think of at least four different ways to do this, but I hate all of them.

Please give me an elegant solution.

Comment: What's wrong with a while loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
food_array = []
while len(food_array) < 100:
    item = 20*np.random.uniform(-1,1,3)
    if mag(item) >= 4:
        food_array.append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to avoid adding a point until you've got a good one.

```
for Food in xrange(100):
    while True:
        point = 20*np.random.uniform(-1,1,3)
        if mag(point) >= 4:
            break
    food_array[Food] = point
```

I might extract a method out of this to make the logic clearer and allow you to use a list comprehension.

```
def generate_point(min_radius):
    while True:
        point = 20*np.random.uniform(-1,1,3)
        if mag(point) >= min_radius:
            return point

food_array = [generate_point(min_radius=4) for i in xrange(100)]
```